# Windows - how to clone network connections entry to another machine

Tags: windows, configuration, modem, clone, gprs

Let's assume we have two Windows XP computers with identical hardware configuration, including GPRS modem connected to COM1 serial port. On the first PC we add new modem device, set up gprs connection on this port in "Network connections" folder. How avoid clicking the same procedure on second computer?

Detailed questions:

1. Where are the entries from "Network connections" stored? File, registry? Is there a possibility to clone such entry between PCs?
2. Question as above but regarding modem entry in device manager - can it be exported from one pc and imported on second?

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't figured out how yet, I believe your solution to question 1 might be in **netsh**. *You will have to start the Wired AutoConfig service to gain access to some areas of netsh*

1. From this [Reference](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/WindowsXP/UserTips/Utilities/Usenetshtoconfigureyourlaptopsnicfordifferentnetworks.html) it seems possible to save network settings and restore them later and I would think you can move them to another machine. [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242468) reference.
2. Your second question is a little more sketchy, because you need to make sure the drivers are in place and have all the relevant registry entries with their matching GUIDs. And getting the second Windows XP machine to accept the GUID might not work.

Somehow I have a difficult time believing it wouldn't just be easier to setup the second machine manually.

Comment: It's much more machines, not just two. I'm researching various ways to deploy them properly. I've tried your solution, but id does not export modem connections, only current routes and gateways.

Answer (score 0):

What about the Windows Files and Settings Transfer Wizard?  I believe you can drill down and select modem/dial-up properties for export.